# How to fix problems with following packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I tried to install [AmberTool](http://ambermd.org/#AmberTools). But when I followed the installation manual system told me to install the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install csh flex gfortran g++ xorg-dev \
     zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev patch python-tk python-matplotlib
```

That gave me the following errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 gfortran : Depends: gfortran-4.6 (>= 4.6.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libbz2-dev : Depends: libbz2-1.0 (= 1.0.6-1) but 1.0.6-4 is to be installed
 xorg-dev : Depends: libfontenc-dev but it is not going to be installed

            Depends: libfs-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libice-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsm-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxaw7-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcomposite-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxcursor-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxfont-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxft-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxinerama-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxmu-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxmuu-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxpm-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxrandr-dev
            Depends: libxrender-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxres-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxss-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxtst-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxv-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxvmc-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxxf86dga-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did run `sudo apt-get update` before running this but it did not change anything.

How can I fix those packages and install these dependencies?

Comment: try running `apt-get install -f`

Comment: More of it, the install documentation tells to type: `sudo apt-get install csh flex gfortran g++ xorg-dev \
zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev patch python-tk python-matplotlib`. Try to install those packages one by one to see which one is incorrect.

Comment: look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Some of those packages exist in the universe repository. Not having that installed would cause the install to fail for obvious reasons. You can either enable this through the Update Manager settings or simply by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` again and go back to installing.